# How to link a chart axis to a chart series using the Shinobi iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, shinobi

I added a secondary axis to my chart using `addYAxis:(SChartAxis *)newYAxis`. How do I get the second series linked to the new axis?

I found `(BOOL)isLinkedToSeries:(SChartSeries *)series` in SChartAxis.h.  But how do I create the initial link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have multiple axes on a ShinobiChart, then you can use the `sChart:xAxisForSeriesAtIndex:` and `sChart:yAxisForSeriesAtIndex:` on the `SChartDataSource` protocol.

For example, if you have 2 y-axes, and 2 series, and you want the first series associated with the first axes, and the second axis with the second series then implement the following method on your datasource:

```
- (SChartAxis *)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart yAxisForSeriesAtIndex:(int)index
{
    return chart.allYAxes[index];
}
```